# Hiding a div element when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I'm trying to hide a specific div in my Register.cshtml view if a checkbox is unchecked.

Script code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#profesor').change(function () {
            value = $(this).val();
            if (value == 0) {
                $('#smjer').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#smjer').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Checkbox 'profesor':

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="profesor" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="profesor" class="form-control" id="profesor">
        <span asp-validation-for="profesor" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Div element 'smjer':

```
<div class="form-group" id="smjer">
    <label asp-for="smjer" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="smjer" class="form-control">
            <option>Računarstvo</option>
            <option>Menadžment turizma i sporta</option>
            <option>Održivi razvoj</option>
        </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="smjer" class="text-danger"></span>
```

When I run the project, the input field for 'Smjer' is still there and checking or unchecking the 'profesor' checkbox doesn't hide or show the div element.

Comment: Edited for better understanding of question

Comment: You can use the `if ($(this).is(':checked'))` selector instead of comparing against the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as long as your checkbox has an attribute called `value` with the value "0". But it will only hide it/show it once. When you click again on the checkbox it is not going to hide/show because your checkboxes value is still same.

If you simply want to change the visiblity based on the checked/ unchecked status, use the jQuery `toggle` method.

```
$(function () {

    $('#profesor').change(function () {
         $('#smjer').toggle();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#profesor').change(function () {
            value = $(this).val();
            if (!this.checked) {
                $('#smjer').hide();
            }
            else {
                $('#smjer').show();
            }
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="profesor" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="profesor" class="form-control" id="profesor">
        <span asp-validation-for="profesor" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" id="smjer">
    <label asp-for="smjer" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <select asp-for="smjer" class="form-control">
            <option>Računarstvo</option>
            <option>Menadžment turizma i sporta</option>
            <option>Održivi razvoj</option>
        </select>
            <span asp-validation-for="smjer" class="text-danger"></span>
```